# Streaming a file from one API endpoint to another API Endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a process where I need to download a file from a location.  This file then needs to be posted in 10 mb chunks to another API endpoint.  The file cannot be copied to the server during this process, it must be streamed to the other end point.  I have the following code I am trying to use:

```
try
            {

                int DefaultReadValue = 10485760; 
                int toRead = 10485760;
                int position = 0;

                using (HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;

                    tranfile = await _getVaultFileData.GetVaultFileData(tranfile, token);
                    int fileSize = tranfile.FileSize;
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.GetAsync(tranfile.VaultFileURL, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                    using (Stream readFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    {
                        readFrom.Position = position;
                        if(readFrom.Position >= fileSize)
                        {
                            fileStatus.Status = "Translation send";
                            fileStatus.Error = "";
                            return fileStatus;
                        }
                        if(fileSize - position < toRead)
                        {
                            toRead = fileSize - position;

                        }
                        int bytesRead;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[toRead];
                        int offset = 0; 
                        while (toRead > 0 && (bytesRead = readFrom.Read(buffer, offset, toRead)) > 0)
                        {
                            ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
                            HttpResponseMessage transcriptionPost = await myClient.PostAsync(tranfile.FileTranslationURL, content);
                            toRead -= bytesRead;
                            offset += bytesRead;
                        }
                        toRead = DefaultReadValue;
                    }
                }

            }
```

when I get to the line 
   readFrom.Position = position;

I get the error:
  Specified method is not supported.

If I enable TransferEncodingChunked I get this error:

InnerException = {System.InvalidOperationException: 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' header can not be used when content object is not specified.}

What do I need to do to read the stream in chunks to post to another endpoint?

Comment: Use [StreamContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.streamcontent?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `ByteArrayContent`: `var content=new StreamContent(readFrom);`. Don't use `using` for the stream, `StreamContent.Dispose` will close it when done

Comment: In any case, there's no need to use `Position` to start reading from *any* stream. With a file stream `Position = 0` would result in a wasted operation. Network streams can only be read though, so setting the position isn't possible